# How do I uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008 from my computer?

Tags: sql-server-2008, uninstall

I've just set up SQL Server 2008 Express on my computer, kind of as a learning tool. Unfortunately I've seem to installed a number of instances to get it working. I would like to uninstall all but one server as it's taking up memory.

I'm not sure how to do that. I can disconnect it from SQL Server Management Studio but it's still there when I reconnect to it.

Is there some sort of screen I can go to, where it shows all the instance of SQL Server on my computer and where I can delete them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to uninstall the instances that you don't want. Removing them from SQL Server Management Studio doesn't remove them from your computer. This article should help:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx